# Duplication trigger is not working as expected

Tags: apex, soql, duplicate-management

Hi friends we have preventing users to create new leads with same email id.But trigger is needs to fire only when record creation.

Everything is working fine.But when i try to upload leads through data loader Some leads are getting error like already lead with same email id is existing in organisation.

When i check there are no leads avilable in organisation with same mail id.If then i try to create a lead manually i can able to create.

I didn't find why is happening like this

My apex class

```
public class LeadDuplication {
    public static void LeadVerification(List<Lead> LeadTriggers)
    {
        Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Leads'].Id;
        List<Lead> LeadIDs = new List<Lead>();
        List<String> LeadEmails = new List<String>();
        List<Lead> Emailverification = new List<Lead>(); 
        for (Lead l : LeadTriggers)
        {
            if(l.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && l.Email <> null ) 
            {
                    // Loop through and add caseId's to the list.
                     LeadIDs.add(l);
                     LeadEmails.add(l.Email);
            }
        }
        Emailverification =[Select Id,Email,RecordTypeId from Lead where 
                            RecordTypeId=:recordTypeId AND Isconverted = false AND Isdeleted= false 
                            AND Email=:LeadEmails];
        For(Lead ls:LeadTriggers){
        if(Emailverification.size()>0) 
        {
           ls.addError('An open/active lead with the same information exists');
        }  
      }
    }
}
```

Trigger Code:

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate ) {

        //It will call a static method called FssteamMapping in FssTeamUpdate.
        FssTeamUpdate.FssteamMapping(Trigger.New);
        LgsTeamLead.LgsTeamLeadMapping(Trigger.New);
        Qualifier.QualificationScore(Trigger.New);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last loop is not bulkified.

```
Emailverification =[Select Id,Email,RecordTypeId from Lead where 
                   RecordTypeId=:recordTypeId AND Isconverted = false AND Isdeleted= false 
                   AND Email=:LeadEmails];
```

First you are querying for any existing leads matching all the email ids of the leads being inserted. So lets say there is a matching lead existing for one of the two leads being inserted. So error should be for one lead and the other one should insert.

```
    For(Lead ls:LeadTriggers){
    if(Emailverification.size()>0) 
    {
       ls.addError('An open/active lead with the same information exists');
    }
```

What you are doing in this section is that, irrespecting of the lead in the loop you are checking of the previous query result, which is having one record(remember, one matching lead found). So the if condition is always true. So for all record in your trigger, it will add an error.

You should create a set of all the lead email ids returned in the query and then check in the for loop if the set contains the email id of the lead being inserted.

```
set<String> matchedLeadEmailIds = new Set<String>();
for(Lead l : [Select Id,Email,RecordTypeId from Lead where 
                            RecordTypeId=:recordTypeId AND Isconverted = false AND Isdeleted= false 
                            AND Email=:LeadEmails])
  {
    matchedLeadEmailIds.add(l.email);
  }

For(Lead ls:LeadTriggers){
  if(matchedLeadEmailIds.contains(ls.Email)) 
  {
     ls.addError('An open/active lead with the same information exists');
  }  
}
```

This will ensure that only the leads with matching email ids are error-ed out

Comment: It's working like charm with my own set of requirements  @Santanu Halder

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason could be leads will same duplicate email id exists for other recordtypes.

> Here you have verified the duplicate leads based on recordtype.

If you need to prevent duplicate email id across Lead records then dont use recordtype to verify the following condition

`if(l.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && l.Email <> null )`

Comment: I read the question as the trigger is flagging dupes when there is non. Seems to me that filter would cause a dupe to potentially not be flagged not increase the possibility of a dup

Comment: I check other record types also those leads with same email id are not having in my organisation.And when i create manually i can able to create.

Comment: can you add trigger code in the question. Also check what Emailverification query is returning

Comment: Ok.But when i try to upload through data import wizard working fine no issues.